# How to generate databricks token through RESTAPI using basic authentication

Tags: postman, azure-databricks, rest

I am trying to generate Databricks token through RESTAPI using basic aunthentication. I am unable to generate the token.

Below is the RESTAPI

```
https://......azuredatabricks.net/basic-auth/api/2.0/token/list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that - you can use only [Databricks Personal Access Token (PAT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/authentication), or use [Azure Active Directory (AAD) Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/) - see linked documentation.  If you have Azure CLI installed on your node, you can use following command to get AAD token: `az account get-access-token --resource=2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d|jq -r .accessToken` (you need to install the `jq` tool). Or you can get [AAD token via REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/service-prin-aad-token#--get-an-azure-active-directory-access-token)